# calculate a boolean flag

Tags: boolean-logic, xor

I have a very basic question related to boolean logic.
I have two boolean flags- `flagA` and `flagB`. I need to calculate `flagC` based on the values of `flagA` and `flagB`.

The code/rules are:

```
    if($flagA && $flagB) {
      $flagC = true; 
    } else if (!$flagA || !$flagB) {
      $flagC = false; 
    } else if(!$flagA && !$flagB) {
      $flagC = true;
    }
```

These rules match with the XNOR truth table - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate

I want to find out different ways to re-write the above code(if possible) with:

- fewer lines of code
- better performance (even if it is a minute difference)
- using bit shifting?

The languages I am hoping to write this in - php, ruby/ruby on rails.
Any help/pointers will be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Your rules are for AND, not XNOR. Which one do you want?

Comment: Yes you are right Juhana. By mistake, I ignored a rule completely. My rules are for AND not XNOR.

Comment: However, the above question arose when I wanted to implement the rules as per XNOR. So I am still curious to know the answers. I updated the rule in the question accordingly.

Comment: In that case, I think my answer below is a pretty simple implementation.

Comment: The logic in the question is still wrong (the first and second ifs cover all possibilities so the third one can never be reached). The logic for XNOR is `c = ( a && b ) || ( !a && !b )`.

Comment: $flagC = true; before the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use these languages much but this might work:

```
$flagC = ($flagA == $flagB);
```

From the link posted:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate

two-input version implements **logical equality**, behaving according to the truth table to the right. A HIGH output (1) results if both of the inputs to the gate are the same. If one but not both inputs are HIGH (1), a LOW output (0) results.

So flagC is true when flagA equals flagB.

Comment: `a == b` is not the same as `a && b`.

Comment: If you look at the link posted: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate  XNOR is true when the two inputs are equal.  From the link:   two-input version implements logical equality, behaving according to the truth table to the right. A HIGH output (1) results if both of the inputs to the gate are the same. If one but not both inputs are HIGH (1), a LOW output (0) results.

Comment: Right, but the code in the question is for AND. Must wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: hmm... guess I am too trusting :)

Comment: Derek, you answered after "understanding" the question with a workable answer. If I could hire additional people to work on programming projects I would pick you. I one upped it with $FlagC = $flagA - $flagB; to be faster, but your answer is more understandable. and maintains type casting, true === true, which is highly desirable to avoid strange behaviors.  Your answer also works in platforms that do not have logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($flagA && $flagB) {
      $flagC = true; 
    } else {
      $flagC = false; 
    }
```

(Your second rule covers all other cases.)

Comment: Or even better: `$flagC = $flagA && $flagB;`